# Learning one mesechta l'ilui Nishmas for two people

Tags: torah-study, mishna, soul

It is customary to learn mishnayos in order to elevate the soul of the deceased. Can one learn one tractate of Mishna and have in mind two deceased people l'ilui nishmasom, or can you only have in mind one mesechta per person?

I know this will not be mentioned in the classical poskim since I looked, but I am sure there are contemporary poskim who address this question. Has anyone seen anyone who addresses this?

Comment: If this worked, why doesn't everyone always have in mind everyone ever?

Comment: I could hear a diff by learning mishnayis, because what schar would the niftar get,it seems he is getting reward for being gorem you to learn ,so if you are doing it for one person than that person is being gorem you,and the second person is a tag along so what reward would be get,obv this is more abstract than halachic, but I wonder if someone discusses it. In short if a relative passes on, one feels a connection and decides to learn ,but for another person a new learning might be needed.

Comment: I think that just as we "*don't know the reward of the Motzvos*" we don't know how the merit on those Mitzvos works. Or how exactly עילוי נשמה works. So just any answer would be equally plausible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as saying Kaddish, where one Kaddish indeed can cover multiple meisim?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember Reb Moshe Feinstein addressing this, but I think it was someone quoting him in one of those likut sfarim, not in the Igros.

Answer (score 3):

Upon further investigation I found in the Rivevos Ephraim Chelek 8:128:2 that it is better to learn one Mishna for one person separately, and if one did learn one Mishna for two people it still works. Unfortunately, Rav Ephraim Greenblatt wrote that he was not well when writing this teshuva to a few questions and said he is,writing in short,so we dont have his reasoning for his answer.

> אברהם הלוי קאלקא שליט"א , אחדשה"ט , קבלתי מכתבך עם השאלות והיות שאני חולה ורתוק למטה אענה בקיצור 
>   בעזהי״ת .
>
> ב ) טוב שילמוד משנה א ' לזכר כל נשמה ובדיעבד אם למד עבור ב ' ג " כ
>   מועיל

Text (אות (ב:

[image]